# How to set max/min on x axis to display time range in Chart.js?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

How do I set the maximum and minimum to display on the x axis? I'd ideally like it to show just the one 24 hour period.
The chart is initialised with the following options:

```
options: {
  scales: {
    yAxes: [{
      ticks: {
        beginAtZero: true,
        max: 120,
        fontFamily: 'FontAwesome'
        }
    }],
    xAxes: [{
      type: 'time',
      time: {
        unit: 'day',
        displayFormats: {
        'day': 'HH:mm'
      }
    },
    distribution: 'series',
    ticks: {
      source: 'data'
    }                                               
  }]
},
```

The max/min is set:

```
chart.options.scales.xAxes[0].ticks.min = dateToday;
chart.options.scales.xAxes[0].ticks.max = dateTomorrow;
```

Dates are date objects at 00:00 hours.

Graph output is:

[image: Chart.js]

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this : 
 yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    suggestedMin: 0,
                    suggestedMax: 100
                }
            }]

It's tested and working for me. you can setup for xAxes as well.